# Is prepending "http://" to a filename for PHP's fopen() safe enough to prevent reading local files?

Tags: php, security, fopen

I have a PHP script that accepts a file URL by GET and opens it with fopen.
Is this solution safe enough or is it a security breach?

```
$filename = $_GET['file'];
if( substr( $filename, 0, 7 ) !== 'http://' )
    $filename = 'http://'.$filename;

fopen( $filename, 'r' );
// etc...
```

This way you can't force a local path to the script to read from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That *should* work, but here are two more things to think about:

- Giving access to other servers.  If your server is behind a firewall, someone could use this to fetch data from another server behind your firewall (or hit a service, etc.) using HTTP, FTP, etc.
- Recursive denial of service.  Make sure that there's not a way for someone to give you the
  URL of the script itself to fetch in a way that makes a recursion loop.

Comment: I would add that if you allow an arbitrary URL to be provided, then you'll have to be very careful in how you process the data you read from that URL, since an attacker could set up a web server to feed any arbitrary data back to you.

Comment: thanks! great answers, will watch out for them. @John: there's no harm in the processing, I only read numbers from the file and they're cast into int to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure, but you might need to escape it also to be safe.

```
$filename=escapeshellarg ( $filename );
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: `fopen()` is not a shell function -- it does not pass its arguments to a shell to evaluate them. So `escapeshellarg()` is not really relevant.

Answer (score 1):

It's sort of fragile, as the security depends on the `http` handler being registered. What if in a future version of PHP it will be removed or optional?

Here's the problem. This actually works (after a warning):

```
stream_wrapper_unregister('http');
file_get_contents('http://../../../../../etc/passwd');
```

Answer (score 0):

another safety measure / option is to use `chroot()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.chroot.php

Comment: you could chroot to an empty directory that you would use as a sandbox, that way even if somebody did get through with a malicious request that could access some data on your file system, chroot would prevent them from going anywhere out of that directory, which would be empty